# NODE.JS vs Windows Service

Tags: node.js, performance, web, service

pretty sure i'm not on right stack, if so please post a link on which I should ask this question.

I'm preparing a Game Design Document for a multiplayer online game and my friend and me are arguing about what is the best between a Node.JS server and a server running as a windows service (or any other compiled language : java, C++, C#).

He's pretty sure that Node.JS is the future and went as far as tell me that popular game's server (like Assassin's creed or WoW) would be made in Node.JS if it existed back in the time.

For me, i'm pretty sure that Running application is still better than the Web thing.

Please, if you vote for a `Close` at least tell me why, if it's because it's not the right stack. Send the like to the right stack. I think it's a legit question.

Comment: Is this a server for an online game which multiple clients are going to connect to, or are you talking about a single player game running locally on the user's machine?

Comment: @JohnMunsch multiplayer online game